# Multiple Inheritance using Anonymous class in Java

Tags: java, anonymous-class

I know that multiple inheritance is not supported in java. I wrote the code as shown below.

```
abstract class abc {
    public abstract void print();
}

abstract class xyz {
    public abstract void print();
}

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        abc obj1 = new abc() {
            public void print() {
                System.out.println("abc");
            }
        };

        xyz obj2 = new xyz() {
            public void print() {
                System.out.println("xyz");
            }
        };

        obj1.print();
        obj2.print();       
    }
}
```

The output produced is:

```
abc
xyz
```

My question is, here **I am using two abstract classes with a concrete class. Isn't that an implementation of multiple inheritance**?
And I intend to implement the code using classes, not interfaces.

Comment: That's called composition.

Comment: You can have multiple inheritance for interfaces with default methods.

Comment: **Isn't that an implementation of multiple inheritance?**. No, rather it is inheritence done multiple times

Comment: Inheriting a superclass in two different places doesn't make it multiple inheritance.

Comment: This is composition, not inheritance

Comment: @DenysSéguret It would be composition if `obj1` and `obj2` were instance variables of the `Test` class. Currently they are local variables of the main method, so I'm not sure this counts as composition.

Answer (score 3):

> I am using two abstract classes with a concrete class. Isn't that an implementation of multiple inheritance?

No, you are creating instances of two anonymous classes in your `main` method. There is no inheritance relation between the `Test` class and any of the two anonymous class instances created.

There is single inheritance relation between the `abc` class and the anonymous class that extends it.

There is another single inheritance relation between the `xyz` class and the anonymous class that extends it.

Comment: I disagree with "there is no inheritance" - `new abc() { ... }` is a subclass of `abc`. You probably meant "there is no multiple inheritance here"

Comment: @AndrewTobilko yes, I was inaccurate. I should have said there is no inheritance relation between the Test class and the two anonymous class instances.

Comment: Okay, I get your point. But using this method, I am still able to use the functionalities of both other classes in the Test class. Isn't that the purpose of inheritance?

Answer (score 2):

An example of multiple inheritance is

```
interface IA {
    default void printOne() { System.out.println("one"); }
}
interface IB {
    default void printTwo() { System.out.println("two"); }
}
class C implements IA, IB {
}

C c = new C():
c.printOne();
c.printTwo();
```

The sample class have multiple interfaces it inherits directly from.

What Java doesn't allow is multiple inheritance of a super class.

Comment: As a side note: Technically, an interface is **implemented**, not *extended*. It's not clear if one would call this *inheritance* too. See the following discussion: [If I implement an Interface, is it called an Inheritance?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/316893/if-i-implement-an-interface-is-it-called-an-inheritance).

Comment: @Zabuza to add to the confusion, the implementation is entirely in the interfaces, not the class which `implements` them.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not multiple inheritance.

Multiple inheritance means that the same derived class inherits from multiple base classes: 
[image]

Your classes each have their own base class.

Note that you *can* have multiple inheritance of interfaces in Java.